# What side dish should I have with saltimbocca?

Tags: italian-cuisine

What is traditionally the side dish you eat with saltimbocca a la romana?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would venture to say there is no one specific traditional side dish.  If you go to Italy you aren't going to see saltimbocca with a side of anything on the menu.  You can pick you primi and contorni yourself.  I think s very simple mixture of roasted or grilled asparagus and/or squash would be very nice.

If your wanting traditional and you are making a roman style saltimbooca (saltimbocca alla romana) You can try to pick a primi and contorni that would be common and traditional to that region.  For example you can do "bucatini all'amatriciana" as a primi. With a nice fennel and orange and/or artichoke salad as a side  And of course to the season it is being prepared.  To me that is really what is "traditional" Italian cooking.

Answer (score 0):

When I was much younger I worked at an 'authentic' Italian restaurant and I seem to recall that Fettuccine Alfredo was our standard side with chicken saltimbocca.

The Food Network's [Giada De Laurentiis](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/giada-de-laurentiis/chicken-saltimbocca-recipe/index.html) recommends [Penne with Treviso and Goat Cheese](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/giada-de-laurentiis/penne-with-treviso-and-goat-cheese-recipe/index.html)
as a side dish with her saltimbocca.